# VS Code: Problems with filesystem in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, filesystems

First of all I ask you to be patient with my English since I'm  not very good at speaking this language.
I'm new in the world of VS Code but I wanted to build a little program that should take a directory from keyboard-input, find it and do some stuff with every file inside this directory .
Before debugging, the program doesn't show any error (it even try to autocomplete the world filesystem [here it is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15fvy.png)), but when I try to debug, I receive the error: "'filesystem' is not a namespace-name".
I already searched for a problem like this one but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem.
The version of g++ I'm using is the 9.2.0, I set c++17 like many others users told to do [(Here's the setup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsia6.png). The library  works just fine. So I honestly don't know what I can do now to resolve this problem. Here's the code:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(){

  cout<<"Directory: ";
  std::string target = "";
  cin>>target;
 
  //while (){  //directory not empty
      //Do some stuff
  }
}
```

[Edit]: Here's the [task.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFEbU.png) and [launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSWoi.png), it's almost (if not all) generated automatically.

Comment: I'm  not familiar with VS Code but (from my experience with Visual Studio), there may be *separate* settings for different configurations (i.e. one for the "Release" build and one for "Debug"). That would explain why it works without the debugger ... maybe.

Comment: the setting is related to intellisence, you need to modify `launch.json`, Is `namespace fs = std::filesystem;` valid C++ and what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

also put

```
-lstdc++fs
```

in your `tasks.json`

Answer (score 0):

I was using g++ 9.2.0 and met exactly the same problem. The settings of c++17 you changed in IDE (VS Code) only offered a standard for checking grammatical mistake, so the library works. But when you start compiling, the c++17 gramma is not accepted by current version of g++. I have found it online that only g++ version of 10.1.0 or newer support c ++17 and I upgraded g++ to the newest 11.2.0, than the compiling runs. May this helps.